# Executing SPIN rule outside of TBC

Tags: java, sparql, topbraid-composer, spin-rdf

I created a spin rule with TBC to query my ontology. I don't want to use TopBraid Composer every time I want to execute the SPIN rule. Is there anyway to automatic invoke the SPIN rule. I heard about the SPIN API. Anybody got some code examples how to execute a SPIN rule on your ontology automatically by calling a method or code for instance?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: http://topbraid.org/spin/api/

There is a forum where you might get answers: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/topbraid-users

Comment: thank you AndyS, im still hoping that somebody might answer my question. This is a very crucial thing!

Comment: The distribution contains examples, see http://www.topquadrant.com/repository/spin/org/topbraid/spin/2.0.0/spin-2.0.0-distribution.zip

Comment: thank you AKSW i will look into it and hopefully find my answer!